# @Function Annotation in Mule

Tags: function, annotations, components, mule

I want to use `@Function` Annotation in Mule. I found only 
[this page](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Function+Annotation) about it.

but I can not get good result.

I made a new project, added a Java component, created a new class and copied this code

```
public class MyComponent {
    public Object process(@XPath("/Envelope") Document doc
                                        @Function("uuid") String id) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

but I have lot of errors. I think I must configure other things but I don't know what, nor how I can use `@Function`.

Comment: The code you're showing doesn't use `@Function`...

Comment: @DavidDossot excuse me i edited my code

Comment: @DavidDossot can u help me or expalain more ? can u explain other steps

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually declare an annotation parser in your configuration in order for annotations to be processed.

Consider this POJO:

```
package com.acme;

import org.mule.api.annotations.expression.XPath;
import org.mule.api.annotations.expressions.Function;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class AnnotatedPojo
{
    public Object process(@XPath("/Envelope") final Document doc, @Function("uuid") final String id)
    {
        return "Envelope text: " + doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent() + " - ID: " + id;
    }
}
```

You can use it with this Mule configuration:

```
<spring:bean class="org.mule.config.endpoint.RegistryBackedAnnotationsParserFactory" />

<flow name="testAnnotatedPojo">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/pojo"
        exchange-pattern="request-response" />

    <component class="com.acme.AnnotatedPojo" />
</flow>
```

Example call:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/xml" http://localhost:8080/pojo -d'<Envelope>foo</Envelope>'
Envelope text: foo - ID: 9133fc7d-a07f-11e2-b560-4d5f883736c4
```