# I want to use a common set of functions used in Mule such as a counter, UUID generator, date and timestamps

Tags: function, annotations, components, mule, mule-studio

I want to use a common set of functions used in Mule such as a counter, UUID generator, date and timestamps.

I found only [this page](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Function+Annotation) about it.

but i have not any information about @Function Annotation in Mule
if anyone has any information please share with me and help me

Comment: @DavidDossot Any Help or suggestions.

Comment: Do you need to access these functions within you custom java code or within the flow?

Comment: @genjosanzo I could get good result, I think to need other configure for run .  but I could work with Function Annotation , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add an annotation parser to your configuration to enable annotations:

```
<spring:bean class="org.mule.config.endpoint.RegistryBackedAnnotationsParserFactory" />
```

See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15886999/387927) for a longer example.